# 'Everyone' permissions on windows folders

Tags: windows-10, permissions, acl, vulnerabilities

i've noticed the following folders have `everyone` permissions:

```
c:/Windows/System32/DriverStore
c:/Windows/System32/spool
```

1. Is this default Windows behavior or some kind of ugly fix?
2. If the mentioned folders are not shared (NTFS/CIFS) and permissions are restricted to `ReadAndExecute/Synchronize`, is there any chance these permissions get exploited?

FWIW, the computer is domain joined (Windows 10 Enterprise).

Comment: I don't see a reason that enumerating the files in the driver store can cause any damage.  The windows spooler.. on the other hand might present vulnerabilities.. but not REAL ones (as in exploit.. more like privacy) there have been so many in the past here in the spooler.. it's really hard to lock this down and yet give people what they want (I was a win32 print driver engineer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me those "everyone" permissions are restricted to the following 3 items:

- Read & Execute
- List Folder Contents
- Read

Under `Spool` the `PRINTERS` and `SERVER` directories are further restricted. Presumably it is under these directories that the system printer drivers "spool" the data before sending to printers or servers.

At worst it means that someone can list out what drivers your system might have. Normal users have no write access to those areas, nor can they affect things outside of handing data to system printing software which *does* have access to write to those areas.

There is no real security issue because in order to do anything your computer needs to be able to read driver information to begin with. You plug something in, you need to scan for drivers, you use the device. Your programs might need to get printer colour profile information (stored among the drivers) in order to print shades accurately.

You can't *change* the drivers because you don't have write access to those areas, only the admin does.

The absolute worst is that someone can look in those folders and say "hey, they had an Epson printer connected". That is only helpful if you know of an escalation of privilege attack involving those drivers, just being able to read them does not automatically make them any more insecure than being able to read the contents of the `system32` folder.

Comment: Yes and no @Mokubai.  Most print drivers are now user mode drivers (I have written 180 of them).  The most someone could do is LOOK AT WHAT YOU PRINTED.  Hope nobody printed a document full of passwords using a hardware font ;).    Not saying that people can.. but that is the most they could do.  One would also need to be able to read and decode the EMF format.  This is still a nice post.